# CSS Animation w/ keyframes

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to make an animation where a picture moves to left and to the right in a loop. 
By using keyframes I've achieved this, but my next step was to `transform:scaleX(-1)` the image instantly when the image reaches 25% and 50% and so on.. All help is appreciated!

```css
div.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

div.object {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  left: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 40px;
  }
  25% {
    left: -60px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 40px;
  }
  75% {
    left: -60px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post a snipped or demo on jsbin or fiddler somewhere

Comment: When you say transform instantly at 25% and 50%, what do you mean?  Does it move between different values or just transform to `scaleX(-1)`?

Comment: I've converted your keyframes animation into a simple snippet to show the animation working.  As part of this, I reduced your `left` values by a factor of 10 (400px -> 40px, etc.) to allow the animation to display gracefully in the snippet renderer.

Comment: Does scale supports `-1`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about how you want to use `transform: scaleX(-1);` in your animation, but the principle of what you are looking to achieve is definitely valid.

Essentially, my understanding is that you want to run the animation that moves your element, and at specific intervals immediately apply a `transform` without it being gracefully animated.

In order to achieve this, add a second animation and run it along-side the first:

```
animation: move 4s infinite, transformScale 4s infinite;

@keyframes transformScale {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(-0.25);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(-0.25);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scaleX(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(-0.25);
  }
}
```

Of course, this will run exactly as the first animation, with the transition between keyframes.  The solution is to use:

```
animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
```

Which results in the `animation` CSS of:

```
animation: move 4s infinite, transformScale 4s infinite steps(1, end);
```

Here's a snippet that shows it in action.

```css
div.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

div.object {
  animation: move 4s infinite, transformScale 4s infinite steps(1, end);
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  left: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 40px;
  }
  25% {
    left: -60px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 40px;
  }
  75% {
    left: -60px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 40px;
  }
}

@keyframes transformScale {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(-0.25);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(-0.25);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scaleX(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(-0.25);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>
```